# Finding certain nouns in web article in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've scraped a few web articles using Beautifulsoup. After scraping these Id like to find out what country the article is talking about. My current method is this
- Extract the raw text from that article
- Have a list of all 195 countries in a list
- Using the findall() function in Beautifulsoup check how many occurances there are.

```
def find_country(url_string):
     html = urlopen(url_string)
     bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

     countryList = bsObj.find_all("p", string="UK")
     print(len(countryList))
```

I tried this for a site such as this : https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-52701843 and didnt the get the correct result.
However, I read online that specify which parent/child the information should be obtained from. i.e I want to obtain the UKs in the

region of the news website. However, I was wondering how I would implement this. So that find_all('p', string=UK) would find the correct amount of the key word UK in the news article.
Thanks for any help, highly appreciated.

Comment: Try this, ```bsObj.find_all("p", text=re.complie("UK"))``` (import re at the top)

Comment: Hey, this worked a lot better than before. Thanks a lot @Sushanth Could you explain why this works better than the other method? Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Sushanth also, I have a code in my  program which looks like this `href=re.compile("^(/news/uk.*)")):`. How would i do something like this href=re.compile("^(/news/{}.*)".format(country))): i.e have variable there instead. Doing this seems to cause an error